# Two abelian groups of order 99 are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra

By using the fundamental theorem of finite abelian group I know that there are two possibilities $\mathbb{Z}_9 ×\mathbb{ Z_{11}}$ and $\mathbb{Z_3} × \mathbb{Z_3} × \mathbb{Z_{11}}$. But i  don't know whether the two abelian groups are isomorphic

Comment: You are so close.  Consider the factor $\mathbb{Z}_9$ versus $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Does $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ have an element of order 9?

Comment: Z_3 x Z_3 has no element of order 9 i know that but the hint is not vivid to me

Comment: The other one does.

Comment: @Jone one to one group homomorphisms preserve order